# Flutter: Having issues in implementing custom barcode scanning feature

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to add a bar code scanning feature in my app that scans a bar code, prompt user to take relevant actions and the again returns to scanning ( something like callback). I cam across some plugins but those not offering what i want. what i am aiming is:

1. Scanning feature on main view (instead of opening another activity
   that does the scanning)
2. Custom Scanning screen ( rounded border and blinking red line to indicate its reading)

   [image]
3. A beep sound to indicate that bar code scanned.

The closest solution i found is available [here](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_qr_mobile_vision), however, it crashes on devices below API 21 (I guess because it uses google's mobile vision). I am still new to flutter and asking for assistance in achieving a concrete solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi so this is the developer of the qr_mobile_vision library that you linked to. There was a bug in the flutter engine that was causing failures on devices older than lollipop; follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_qr_mobile_vision/issues/45#issuecomment-433713182) to update to a version of flutter without the issue. If you still see problems feel free to open a bug in the plugin and I'll take a look when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the given instructions, but App completely crashes at start up. As you advised, i will wait for it to be released in master :)

Comment: @rmtmckenzie i am sill not able to complete the scanning feature of my app. The qr_mobile_vision was successfully added to the project. however, it is not able to read/ scan anything. can you assist me in fixing this issue? i can not figure out where the problem is :(

Comment: I'm not sure when I'm going to have a chance to look at it, but if you can't get it to work you should [open a bug in the github repository](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_qr_mobile_vision/issues/new). Please include a printout of `flutter doctor`, your pubspec, the code where you're using QrCamera, and a log of when you try running (if anything relevant is in it)

Comment: @SDevjani Have you found any solution?